# Display a message in either Visual Sourcesafe or Visual Studio on opening a project\solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

We've migrated a couple of projects\solutions from a legacy VSS database to subversion.  We want to keep the VSS copies around for history, but continue development using svn for version control.  There's a small risk some people might still try and get the VSS version without realizing they should be looking in subversion or where the subversion repository is.

I've set all users to "read-only" for the projects in question on VSS, but is there a better way draw users attention to the fact if they accidently get the VSS version out and point them to the right place?

For example, is it possible to either display a messagebox in VSS or in Visual studio when they open the solution?  Or automatically open a file in Visual studio if someone gets the VSS solution and opens it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this looks pretty dead, I'll share my current solution.  If no-one has a better suggestion, I'll just assume there is no better way to handle it:

1. As mentioned in the question I have set the all users to Read-Only access for the project
2. I renamed the project folder in VSS so it ends with -Migrated-To-SVN
3. I renamed the solution file in VSS so it end with -Migrated-To-SVN